# Use ACL to grant permission to only upload a file to specific path in GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, acl, gsutil

I created a service account. Its only job is to upload data to a specific path in a GCS bucket e.g. `gs://bucket/current/`. In this path, this service account should be able to create a folder like `2019/` and upload data to `gs://bucket/current/2019/file.csv` This account will not be able to view other paths in this bucket except `gs://.../current/...` and after uploading data to this path, the file cannot be deleted or edited.

I don't think that I can use IAM to grant a permission like this. So, I've looked into `acl` and `defacl` but couldn't find a way to make this work. How can I use `acl` to grant a service account for this task?

Edit: Thank you for helping me improve the readability of this question. I have read [google document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) which have lots of example about acl but I cannot find one that match to my question.

Edit2: I've tried this `gsutil acl ch -r -u serviceaccount:W gs://bucket/current/` 
and I got this result:

`Skipping serviceaccount:W on gs://bucket/current/, as WRITER does not apply to objects
No changes to gs://bucket/current/`

which make sense because right now there is no object in that path. What I wanted to do is just want this service account to only do a view only this GCS path and be able to upload a file to the bucket

My solution: Instead of using ACL, I used IAM permission and grant a role of storage.objectCreator in the bucket to that service account

Comment: HI, I would advise you to not give WRITER permission, since it is not only to create objects, but also to overwrite and delete them, which is not what you want. I'm testing to see if you can give `roles/storage.objectCreator` to a service account for a path in the bucket. That role allows users to create objects, and it does not give permission to view, delete, or overwrite objects.

Comment: I confused by the term 'create' of this role. Does it include uploading file? And if this work. do I still need to apply ACL to make sure that this service account cannot do any action except upload?

Comment: Oh If I used the same command as in edit2 but change to READ permission, will it work? like it can only view object in that path.

Comment: When you upload a file that doesn't already exist, you create it. Applying a certain IAM policy, you don't need to set an additional ACL. Using IAM permissions or ACL are [two different options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/), you only need one.

Comment: So, `roles/storage.objectCreator` seems to solve my problem, right? I wonder how to test after granting this role to the service account. By the way, if I don't use IAM but use ACL instead, will there be a way? just really curious (someone told me like that and they left me finding a way which I have no idea)

Comment: After several tests, my conclusion is that you cannot have the permission configuration you were asking for, not with IAM or ACL. At least, I haven't been able to.

Comment: The IAM `roles/storage.objectCreator` is not work?

Comment: No, unfortunately it gives me a 400 error with message `roles/storage.objectCreator is not a valid role for projects/_/buckets/my-bucket/objects/current/#0`

Comment: omg the end is near SOS

Comment: what command did you try? I tested it and I am be able to upload the file and also create a folder within it @alextru

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193376/discussion-between-alextru-and-jamiewp).

Comment: Hello @Jamiewp!
I have seen in the chat that you have found your answer with @alextru, great! Would you mind posting it as an answer here so that other community members may benefit from your findings?
Thank you!