# Applying an ACL to a google storage bucket item using PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to upload an item to a google storage bucket (using my admin key), and apply an ACL to it, namely one specific other (service account) user should have READ access.

My code so far, which doesn't apply the ACL for some reason:

```php
$myGoogleKey = 'admin-key.json';
$theirGoogleKey = 'google-key.json';

// reading the user e-mail from their key
$account = json_decode(file_get_contents($theirGoogleKey), false)->client_email;
echo "Account: $account\n";

$storage = new StorageClient(
    [
        'keyFilePath' => $myGoogleKey
    ]
);

$bucket = $storage->bucket('my-bucket');
$fileSource = fopen('my-file', 'rb');

$acl = new \Google\Service\Storage\ObjectAccessControl();
$acl->setEntity('user-' . $account);
$acl->setRole('READER');
$acls = new \Google\Service\Storage\ObjectAccessControls();
$acls->setItems([$acl]);

$bucket->upload($fileSource, [
    // 'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead', // all public, but not what I want
    'name' => 'my-file',
    'metadata' => [
        'acl' => [
            $acls
        ]
    ]
]);
```

The upload works without error, but when I look in the ACL settings via browser, the account has not been given read access (and cannot read the file, I tried, "no permission").

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the upload method in your code. You may have a look at this [documentation](https://artisansweb.net/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-using-php/).

Comment: @MousumiRoy that link only illustrates the `'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'` which I already have in my code, commented out because I don't want publicRead

Comment: You may have a look at this [stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128249/use-acl-to-grant-permission-to-only-upload-a-file-to-specific-path-in-gcs-bucket).